# Get data from JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get data from the following JSON file using PHP. I specifically want "temperatureMin" and "temperatureMax".

It's probably really simple, but I have no idea how to do this. I'm stuck on what to do after file_get_contents("file.json"). Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
    "daily": {
        "summary": "No precipitation for the week; temperatures rising to 6° on Tuesday.",
        "icon": "clear-day",
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1383458400,
                "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",
                "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
                "sunriseTime": 1383491266,
                "sunsetTime": 1383523844,
                "temperatureMin": -3.46,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1383544800,
                "temperatureMax": -1.12,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1383458400,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Get the content of the JSON file using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://example.com/example.json/');
```

Now decode the JSON using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
```

You have an associative array containing all the information. To figure out how to access the values you need, you can do the following:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

This will print out the contents of the array in a nice readable format. Note that the second parameter is set to `true` in order to let `print_r()` know that the output should be *return*ed (rather than just printed to screen). Then, you access the elements you want, like so:

```
$temperatureMin = $json['daily']['data'][0]['temperatureMin'];
$temperatureMax = $json['daily']['data'][0]['temperatureMax'];
```

Or loop through the array however you wish:

```
foreach ($json['daily']['data'] as $field => $value) {
    // Use $field and $value here
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/60114)

Comment: Thanks! But I seem to be having a problem with the degree symbol in the JSON, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @HaroldDunn: I don't understand what you mean by `degree symbol` -- could you clarify?

Comment: "No precipitation for the week; temperatures rising to 6° on Tuesday." includes the degree symbol (°) in it. This seems to cause your demo to echo nothing when I try it on my site.

Comment: @HaroldDunn Care to share your solution? I suspect I may be having a similar problem...

Comment: @JonnyNineToes: Try setting `header('charset=utf8');` at the very top of your script.

Answer (score 13):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to transform your JSON into a PHP array. Example:

```
$json = '{"a":"b"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['a']; // b
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Try:
$data = file_get_contents ("file.json");
        $json = json_decode($data, true);
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
            } else {
                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                    echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what about three, four, etc. dimensinal arrays? Also, OP didn't ask to echo result