# How nodejs and php can share the same config file to access database?

Tags: php, node.js

Here is my php config file I use (config.php)

```
<?php 

class DbConfig{   
    const NAME = 'myDB';
    const USER = 'myUser';
    const PASS = 'myPass';
    const HOST = 'localhost';
}

class Servers {
    const NODE = 'http://127.0.0.1';
    const RTMP = 'http://127.0.0.1:1935/';   
}

?>
```

I would like to use this DBConfig inside my nodejs (I use npm mysql package).

What is the best way/strategy to have 1 single config file for both PHP and NODEJS ?

Regards

Comment: json, csv or xml are all easily parseable. What did you try so far?

Comment: I did not try anything. I have now 2 configs files which upsets me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [12 factor app](http://12factor.net/config) use environment variables.
Sensitive credentials should not be checked into your version control repo.

If you cannot use environment variables, I would advise using something like a file outside of version control like /config/database.json

You can easily parse .json in [Node as defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-object-into-server-memory) or [PHP defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758954/get-data-from-json-file-with-php).