# PHP | Failing to get local json file data

Tags: php, json

I have a piece of code:

```
$pricesGrab = file_get_contents("prices.json", true);
$prices = json_decode($pricesGrab, true);
```

But for some reason the `$prices` is null for me. I have checked everything in my opinion: The file has data, file has minified JSON, JSON is valid.. I don't know what could be the issue now. I can't put JSON here, it's too big, if it's needed I can try to find a uploda site.

Comment: Why are you using `include path`  and what is the content of `$pricesGrab`?

Comment: Also if file is loaded right this `json_last_error(); / json_last_error_msg();` can help debugging.

Comment: Oh, that true I left there, but it doesn't change anything and by the content you want me to upload the JSON data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758954/get-data-from-json-file-with-php

Comment: I just want to know if the content was loaded right. You dont check this with your code.

Comment: replace this $pricesGrab = file_get_contents("prices.json", true); with $pricesGrab = file_get_contents("prices.json");

Comment: Seems like the json_last_error() has solved my issue!